# Why does this backup batch file create hidden system folder as destination?

Tags: batch-file, xcopy

I got this batch file from here and works well. The only issue I am having is that the folder to creates (or even uses if already present) becomes a hidden system folder.

```
@echo off
REM get start time
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime /value') do set "dt=%%a"
set "YY=%dt:~2,2%" & set "YYYY=%dt:~0,4%" & set "MM=%dt:~4,2%" & set "DD=%dt:~6,2%"
set "HH=%dt:~8,2%" & set "Min=%dt:~10,2%" & set "Sec=%dt:~12,2%"

REM set "datestamp=%YYYY%%MM%%DD%" & set "timestamp=%HH%%Min%%Sec%"
set "fullstamp=%YYYY%-%MM%-%DD%_%HH%-%Min%-%Sec%"
set "logtimestamp=%YYYY%.%MM%.%DD% %HH%:%Min%:%Sec%"

REM actual copy
set source=%1
set destination=%2

REM create the exclusion list
set exclusion=%3
set exclusion=%exclusion:"=%
(for %%i in (%exclusion%) do echo %%i) > exclusion.txt

REM set the file name for the logging data
set log=log-%fullstamp%.txt

REM start the backup process
echo // started backup at %logtimestamp% > %log%
echo // from %~f1 to %~f2\ >> %log%

echo ---- >> %log%
xcopy %source% %destination% /S /E /C /D /R /Y /V /I /EXCLUDE:exclusion.txt >> %log%
echo ---- >> %log%
del /f exclusion.txt

REM get finish time
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime /value') do set "dt=%%a"
set "YY=%dt:~2,2%" & set "YYYY=%dt:~0,4%" & set "MM=%dt:~4,2%" & set "DD=%dt:~6,2%"
set "HH=%dt:~8,2%" & set "Min=%dt:~10,2%" & set "Sec=%dt:~12,2%"
set "logtimestamp=%YYYY%.%MM%.%DD% %HH%:%Min%:%Sec%"

echo // finished backup at %logtimestamp% >> %log%

REM move the logging
if not exist "%destination%\.backup_log" mkdir %destination%\.backup_log
move %log% %destination%\.backup_log
```

Comment: Do not create a directory beginning with a period, they're not fully supported by Windows Explorer. _You may already have some on your system, but they're probably created by lazy Unix programmers, who should be using the Application Data directories._

Comment: I can't duplicate your problem. Is your source folder already a hidden system folder? Are you using this script as part of a larger script?

Comment: Files and folders of which name start with `.` like `.backup_log` are interpreted on UNIX/MAC file systems as hidden files and folders. The Windows batch file does not set hidden attribute on folder `.backup_log` as it would be necessary on Windows file systems to hide the folder. But it is possible that this batch file is executed on a storage media with a UNIX/MAC file system mounted for example with Samba as a drive on Windows and the creation of `.backup_log` instead of `backup_log` makes the folder hidden on UNIX/MAC and so also on Windows mount. That was very good detected by __Compo__.

Comment: @Compo From Windows SDK *•Do not end a file or directory name with a space or a period. Although the underlying file system may support such names, the Windows shell and user interface does not. However, it is acceptable to specify a period as the first character of a name. For example, ".temp".* from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/fileio/naming-a-file

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of your script, with a few changes, the most important one being that the directory name holding the log file(s) has been changed from `.backup_log` to `backup_logs`:

```bat
@Echo Off
SetLocal DisableDelayedExpansion

Rem Actual copy
Set "source=%~1"
Set "destination=%~2"
Set "logdir=%~2\backup_logs"

Rem Create the exclusion list
(For %%A In (%~3)Do Echo(%%A)>"exclusion.txt"

Rem Ensure log directory exists
If Not Exist "%logdir%\" MD "%logdir%"

Rem Get start time
Call :Stamp

Rem Set the file name for the logging data
Set "log=log-%fs%.txt"

Rem Start the backup process
(   Echo // Started backup at %ls%
    Echo // from %~1 to %~2
    Echo ----
    XCopy "%source%" "%destination%" /E /C /D /R /Y /V /I /EXCLUDE:"exclusion.txt"
    Echo ----

    Rem Get finish time
    Call :Stamp
    SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    Echo // Finished backup at !ls!
    EndLocal)>"%logdir%\%log%"
Del "exclusion.txt"
EndLocal
GoTo :EOF

:Stamp
Rem Get date and time stamps
Set "fs="
For /F "Tokens=1-6Delims=/: " %%A In ('RoboCopy /NJH /L "\|" Null'
) Do If Not Defined fs (Set "fs=%%A-%%B-%%C_%%D-%%E-%%F"
    Set "ls=%%A.%%B.%%C %%D:%%E:%%F")
Exit /B
```

You would probably run the script from the Command Prompt using something similar to this:

```bat
C:\Users\Dale>"My Scripts\backup.cmd" Documents D:\Backups\MyDocs ".lnk ~$ \temp\"
```

Comment: I never thought I'd write this on one of your answers, but this doesn't answer the question, since you don't address why their destination folder apparently becomes a hidden system folder.

Comment: TBF, there was a reason for that, I could see absolutely no reason why or how a hidden system folder could be created. Without knowing the values for `%1`, `%2` or `%3`, _(which should really have been provided)_, there may have been one or more invisible characters between `%2` and `%3`. But even if that were the case, I can't see how that would create a super-hidden directory as easily, not even if being run as Administrator, _(which we were also not told)_. The best I could therefore offer by way of solution was a code improvement and show them how to run it using doublequotes where needed.

Comment: %1 is source / %2 is Destination and %3 is exclusions. I originally thought it was because I was using "Backup" as the folder name so I changed it to Ext_backup and get the same results. Even if I create the directory first in explorer and then run the script, it becomes not only hidden, but listed as a system file. Example D:backup.bat X: F:\Ext_Backup $RECYCLE.BIN

Comment: @DaleLawson, are you telling me that you've used my code and in Windows Command Prompt, _`cmd.exe`_ you've run it with the following `D:\backup.bat X:\ F:\Ext_Backup $RECYCLE.BIN` and it has created a hidden system directory when viewed directly in Windows Explorer. If so, take a look at [Mofi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3074564/mofi)'s comment and tell us about the file system on drive `F:`. Can you also try it using `%__AppDir__%xcopy.exe` instead of just `XCopy`, to rule out the remote possibility that your using Windows built-in `xcopy.exe`.

Comment: As an additional precaution, when you open the Command Prompt to run your script with arguments, open it from your start/search using `%windir%\cmd.exe /d`. This should ensure that there are no 'AutoRun' commands executing when it is opened, _these could be making modifications outside of your intended goal_.

Comment: I have not yet tried your version of the script. Will do that tomorrow.

Comment: Got am error saying it couldn't find "exclusion.txt" so I just removed all that. %windir% does not contain the file cmd.exe. It is located at %windir%\System32\cmd.exe and I tried that and no matter what I name the destination folded, it gets created as a hidden system folder.  I also tried replacing xcopy with %__AppDir__%xcopy.exe and got the same results. F: drive is a GPT partitioned drive with NTFS. Tried it on an MBR partition with same results.

Comment: Found this answer in another post. When specifying an entire drive as source, also add source wildcard. Example:

xcopy "S:\*.*" "D:\destdirectory" /D /E /C /R /I /K /Y
then the H and S attributes are not set in the destination.

Comment: Above solution fixed the issue. Not sure why Xcopy wants to set the H and S attribute when only supplying the drive letter without wildcards.

Comment: @Dale, are you reading any of my comments? I asked you if you were using `D:\backup.bat X:\ F:\Ext_Backup $RECYCLE.BIN`, this would mean your batch file was invoking `XCopy "X:\" "F:\Ext_Backup" /E /C /D /R /Y /V /I /EXCLUDE:"$RECYCLE.BIN"`. Had you used that, your only issue would have been the 3rd argument, which is supposed to be one or more files containing match strings, each on a separate line in the files. Your issues therefore are not knowing the difference between a root directory `X:\ ` and a drive `X:` and a failure to read the usage information for the command `XCopy`.